# Cannot read value from .env file in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, environment-variables, application.properties

In my Spring Boot app, I have the following values in my `.env` file located in the project root:

***.env:***

```
DB_NAME=demo_db
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=pass
```

On the other hand, when I set environment variebles on the Run configuration of IntelliJ as shown below, it is working:

```
DB_NAME=demo_db;DB_USERNAME=postgres;DB_PASSWORD=pass
```

So, I have the following questions:

**1.** As far as I know, `.env` file is used to keep environment variables instead of setting. Is that true? Could you explain the usage of it a little bit more (I look at several pages but not a brief explanation).

**2.** Is there any relation of `.env` file with `application.properties` except from reading variable values from `.env` file? I am not sure if there may also be different version o `.env` file e.g. `.env-dev` file ?

Comment: do you have the .envfile plugin installed in IntelliJ? from my experience with it, it's barely working as it is.

Comment: It is standard to use .env for environment variable but more in javascript than in java so Spring will not read this file without any configuration. If you want Spring Boot to read data, you can add an application.properties file beside your jar and it will be read.

Comment: @TomElias I did not installed it. Then, the `.env` file is read by that plugin instead of setting environment variables on InteliJ?

Comment: @grekier I have an `application.yml` file, but could not understand what you mean. As far as I know, `application.yml` can read data from `.env` file, right? If so, do I need to install the plugin on IntelliJ?

Comment: .env file will not be read by default! You need a plugin for that. Assuming you need some value read at runtime, you can add a file called application.properties (or yml) in the same folder that your jar file and those will be read when running the jar. If what you want to achieve is to load it in IntelliJ, either add them to the config or the local ENV

Comment: Can we say that it is the same **reading environment variables from .env file using plugin** AND **reading environment variables from Environment Variables field of IntelliJ run configutation**?

Comment: And, as far as I see, I do not need .env file when running or debugging the app on IntelliJ (I can add necessary variables via run config of IntelliJ). What about when publishing this app to a Docker container? Then, how my ${{ }} fields in the properties file continues to read these environment variables when the app runs on Docker? Any idea?

Comment: @grekier Any reply please about my last comment?

Comment: reading .env with plugin and env from IntelliJ are the same yes. Env is always the same when it is set no matter where it is set from. For Docker, you can either build your image with the env set with CLI in dockerfile (like `export key=value`) if it is an alternative, add it to docker when starting with `-e` flag or use a docker compose file and put them there.

Comment: @grekier Thanks a lot for your help. I have a Dockerfile, how can I add my environment variable to DOckerfile? Could you please post it as answer? And also you can add the other alternative.

Comment: @grekier I think I can use `.env` file for setting env variables for Docker container. https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/

Comment: Chicos, are you there?

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you are mixing up spring boot and InteliJ.

- .env will be used by IntelliJ if you have EnvFile - IntelliJ IDE
  Plugin
- application.properties looked up by spring boot for injecting spring properties

If you are looking to run the application detacted from IDE you should define them in application.propeties defining them in a profile specific approach. Consider this article from offical [spring docs](https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/23/spring-tips-configuration).

Comment: Yes, I am mixed, but although I have `.env` file, IntelliJ cannot read as I mentioned in the question. On the other hand, I don't see anything related to `.env` file on that page. Any clarification?

Comment: The refernece provided was for spring boot env specific configuration. Inorder to make .env work you would need EnvFile - IntelliJ IDE Plugin installed. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: Can we say that it is the same **reading environment variables from .env file using plugin** AND **reading environment variables from Environment Variables field of IntelliJ run configutation**?

Comment: yes, that is the same. and you can reference environment variables in your properties files by using ${{ }} notation

Comment: Yes, I already referenced and read from IntelliJ environment variables. Thanks

Comment: @krishnan Last question: I do not need .env file when running or debugging the app on IntelliJ (I can add necessary variables via run config of IntelliJ). What about when publishing this app to a Docker container? Then, how my ${{ }} fields in the properties file continues to read these environment variables when the app runs on Docker? Any idea?

Comment: Chico, I think I can use `.env` file for setting env variables for Docker container. https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/

Comment: Chicos, are you there?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using the wrong version of the dependency dot-env that I Installed. The latest version caused me issues:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>me.paulschwarz</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-dotenv</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

But when I switched to an older more stable version for this dependency and then boom, the env reading started working in my Spring Boot application. You have to analyze the weekly downloads. The latest version having much less downloads is an indicator of bugs and beta without testing for all cases.

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>me.paulschwarz</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-dotenv</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.4</version>
  </dependency>
```